# Need some help solving high-school level trignometry question.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[here it is](https://imgur.com/bKeOisp).

[image]

I've tried solving it multiple ways but it gets too complicated. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: If you connect OC you can easily find an expression for AC and AB. Then you can use what given about the circumferences. Good luck.

Comment: Is that expression $AB=r\sqrt{2+cos(-2x)$?

Comment: Almost, the right expression is $AB=r \sqrt{2+2cos(2x)}$. How did you get the expression?

Comment: I used the cosine rule. I just seemed to forget that there was a 2 in there

Comment: So we got the expression (BTW, using the sine rule would be easier), what next?

Comment: So it should be easy to show this if you compare three things:  circumference of circle (C$_{o}$ = 2$\pi$r), perimeter (s = C$_{o}$/2 = $\pi$r), and OC$^{2}$ = r$^{2}$ + AC$^{2}$ - 2 r AC cos(x).  Since OC = r, the law of cosines simplifies greatly to: AC = 2rcos(x).

Comment: I've tried plugging it into the equation $2AB+2XAB=2piR/2$. which leads to: $$\sqrt(2+2cosx) = \frac{\pi}{2(x+1)$$. And here is where I get some trouble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\displaystyle \overline{AB}=2rcos(x)=R$$, where R is radius of the shaded circle.
We have $2R+R(2x)=\frac{2\pi r}{2}$ by the condition given, rearrange to get the equality you want to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U = 2 \pi * r$ be the circumference of the circle.
Let $s = AB = AC$ be the radius of the circular arc.
Let $V = \frac{U}{2}$ be the perimeter of the shaded area.

1. Find an equation for $V$:

$$
V = AB + AC + (2 \pi * s) * \frac{2x}{2 \pi} = 2 * s + 2 * x * s = s * (2 + 2x)
$$

It is the sum of $AB$ and $AC$ (which are both $s$) and the partial circumference of the arc $(2 \pi * s) * \frac{2 x}{2 \pi}$.

2. Find an equation for $s$

$$
s = 2 * \cos{x} * r
$$

$OCA$ is an equilateral triangle since both $A$ and $C$ lie on the circumference of the circle with center $O$ and radius $r$

So $\cos{x} * r$ is the length of the adjacent side of a right-angled triangle $ODA$ where $D$ lies in the center of $AC$.

3. Equate both terms for $V$

$$
\frac {U}{2} = s * (2 + 2x) \\ \Leftrightarrow
\pi * r = s * (2 + 2x) \\ \Leftrightarrow
\pi * r = 2 * \cos{x} * r * (2 + 2x) \hspace{10pt} \vert * \frac{1}{r} \\ \Leftrightarrow
\pi = \cos{x} * (4 + 4x) \hspace{10pt} \vert * \frac{1}{4 + 4x} \\ \Leftrightarrow
\frac{\pi}{4 + 4x} = \cos{x} \hspace{10pt} \vert \arccos{} \\ \Leftrightarrow
\arccos{\frac{\pi}{4 + 4x}} = x
$$